# [JS]Manually trimLeft of all whitespace in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I've been trying to create a trimLeft() function and I seem to be drawing blanks on the logic.

I'm not allowed to use built in functions like replace, splice, substr, substring, trim or toString.

I've been rolling with this:

```
function trimLeft(string){
     var noSpace = '';
     for(var o = 0; o < string.length; o++){
         if (string.charAt(o) !== ' ' && string.charAt(o) !== "\t"){
             noSpace += string.charAt(o);
         }
     }
     return noSpace;
 }
 window.alert(trimLeft("|" + "\tAPPLE\t" + "|"));
```

However it removes all whitespace rather than just the left side. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It trims all the whitespace because you're missing any logic to stop replacing spaces once a non-space is encountered.

Comment: Yeah I tried to remedy that with current/next variables but it was messy and downright disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```js
function trimLeft(string) {
    for (var o = 0; o < string.length; o++){
        if (string.charAt(o) !== ' ' && string.charAt(o) !== "\t"){
            return string.substring(o);
        }
    }
}

window.alert("|" + trimLeft("\tAPPLE\t") + "|");
```

Note that as soon as a non-whitespace character is found, the rest of the string is returned immediately.

Also note that the test using `window.alert()` didn't work, because you tested the function with the string `"|\tAPPLE\t|"`, which has no leading whitespace.

Here's a solution wihtout using any built-in string functions:

```js
function trimLeft(string) {
    var noSpace = "";
    var isStart = true; // becomes false as soon as non-whitespace is found
    for (var o = 0; o < string.length; o++) {
        if (!isStart || (string[o] !== " " && string[o] !== "\t")) {
            noSpace += string[o];
            isStart = false;
        }
    }
    return noSpace;
}
window.alert("|" + trimLeft("\tAPPLE\t") + "|");
window.alert("|" + trimLeft("    BANANA  ") + "|");
```

Comment: aha I definitely derped there. Also, I should have noted earlier - I can't use any string built-in functions (trimleft, splice, substr, substring, replace, toStrings, etc)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot @Aloso